# Event that fires when form is made visible on screen

Tags: forms, delphi, events

I have a form that takes some time to create and I would like to show the user that something is happening and I have made a hourglass cursor when I call the function that shows the form. But my problem is that I can't get the

```
Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
```

to execute first when the form is actually displayed on screen.
I have tried all events that makes a bit sense trying but with no luck. The hourglass is gone before the form is visible.

What can I try next to get this working.

I you need more info please say so and I will find it.

I set the hourglass in my mainform before calling the function that creates the form and then I have my form show as below.

```
procedure TfrmJsCv.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fReportFile := Folders.DirDatabase + 'jobsearch_print.mdb';
  btnPrint.Visible := FileExists(fReportFile);
  try
    SetupMain;
    SetupCertificates;
    SetupContacts;
    SetupCourse;
    SetupJobs;
    SetupLanguage;
    SetupLanguageLevels;
    SetupItKnowledge;
    SetupKnowledgeLevels;
    SetupKnowledgeTypes;
    SetupOther;
    SetupReferences;
    SetupSchool;
    SetupYears;
  except
    on E: exception do
      Logfile.Error('F_JsCv.FormShow: ' + E.Message);
  end;
  PagCurriculumVitae.ActivePageIndex := 0;
end;
```

I have tried to put Screen.Cursor := crDefault; on the OnActivate, OnCreate, OnShow, OnResize, OnPaint events but the hourglass is reset before the form is ready/visible on screen

All the Setupxxxxx procedures is procedures that prepares data for the form that is rather complex - it collects data from 12 different tables.

Comment: "I have tried all events": Show us!

Comment: "Show us" - that won't be easy. But OnActivate, OnCreate, OnShow, OnResize, OnPaint has been tried with no luck.

Comment: So what went wrong when you tried to reset the cursor in OnShow?

Comment: Yes it's easy. Highlight the code in your IDE, copy it, paste it here in the question, press Save Edits.

Comment: Why don't you set the hourglass when you begin the long operation, and then revert when it is finished.

Comment: Your exception handler is a disaster too.

Comment: And running all that code in `OnShow` is surely wrong. That even can fire multiple times in principle. What's wrong with initialising in the constructor.

Comment: If a task takes more than 10ms to finish, execute this task in a thread.

Comment: By default I always include an exceptionhandler when I create a function or procedure so I don't forget it when needed - this may cause some to be created that aren't needed but I don't see the harm in that.

Comment: You've got that completely wrong. You should, as a broad rule, not write exception handlers. You are swallowing exceptions. I'm ready to help you learn about this if you are willing.

Comment: @SirRufo Using of secondary thread in OP case would be far from easy since he is doing lots of UI interaction and we all know that you should not access the UI directly from secondary threads.

Comment: @SilverWarior Collecting data is not UI related at first and that can be done in a thread

Comment: I don't see how threading would help here - I need the data to be prepared before showing the form since they are used on the form. So as I see it I will still have to wait until all threads are finished.

Comment: @David Heffernan  -  if you have any docs or links I could benefit from then I would love to see them.  It could be nice with some useful reading when I am in hospital every 14 days.

Comment: Threading would allow you to service the message queue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you showing the form modally? In that case the `crHourGlass` setting is cancelled by the call to `ShowModal` where a call `Screen.Cursor := crDefault;` is made . See `Vcl.Forms` unit, `function TCustomForm.ShowModal: Integer;`
line 7139 (XE7 source).

The cure would be to call `Screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;` in `TfrmJsCv.FormShow()` before all those SetupXXX calls and `Screen.Cursor := crDefault;` after.

Now that OP confirmed that the form was shown modally, I think some more explanation may be beneficial for future readers.

OP said:

> "The hourglass is gone before the form is visible."
>   "I set the hourglass in my mainform before calling the function that creates
>   the form ..."

Thus he has something like this in the main form:

```
  Screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;
  frmJsCv.ShowModal
```

Which ends up in Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.ShowModal

```
...
SaveCursor := Screen.Cursor;
Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
SaveCount := Screen.CursorCount;
...
try
  Show;  // 
  try
    // message loop
  finally
    Hide;
  end;
finally
  if Screen.CursorCount = SaveCount then
    Screen.Cursor := SaveCursor
  else Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
  ...
end;
```

The purpose is obviously to let the modal form manipulate the cursor as needed and then to restore the cursor to what it was before the call to `ShowModal`. This has been the same at least from Delphi 7.

Note that ordinary `Show` doesn't do the above excersize.

Another effect of setting `crHourGlass` before the call to ShowModal, and not setting `crDefault`back afterwards would be that the cursor would still not be shown as an hourglass while the form is shown, but immediately afterwards. This could be as confusing as this explanation :)

Comment: We are talking about the application main form. AFAIK there is no ShowModal for that form in the context of the question

Comment: @Sir We are talking about a secondary form that he is opening *from* the main form. True that he did not say anything about modal, that's why I asked. It explains the symptoms though, so I'm fairly confident (until said otherwise).

Comment: The form is shown modally as you suspected - and that was the problem. I moved the call to hourglass to OnShow and now it is shown correct.  Thanks

Comment: @OZ8HP You are welcome. I add some explanation now that you confirmed my suspicion.